# Tengo un atasco en mi Programa C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Buen día a todos, me hice el usuario porque tengo una duda muy grande y no puedo continuar sin solucionarla.

Estoy tratando de hacer el programa en diferentes archivos ".cs" de clases pero esto me esta trayendo complicaciones a la hora de querer llamar las funciones y modificar las variables de uno a otro.

Tengo la clase Configuración en el archivo Configuración.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1 
{
public class Configuracion
{
    private string directorio;       
    bool etapa;                 // TRUE es etapa Individual, FALSE es etapa grupal

    public bool confOrden;          //TRUE se ejecuta en azar - FALSE Elección de Orden

    private bool tlimite;       //TRUE tiene un limite de tiempo - FALSE no limitado por tiempo
    private int valorlimite;    // Valor del limite de tiempo

    private int repeticiones;   //Cantidad de Repeticiones x Figura
    private int cantFig;        //Cantidad de Figuras

    int[] orden;                 // Cuando se defina repeticiones y cant Fig debemos hacer    ensayo_suj = new int[repeticiones*cantFig];

    public Configuracion()
           {
                directorio = @"\\\\CINTRA-M029\\DatosBuscFiguras";

                etapa = true;    
                tlimite = true; valorlimite = 60;
                confOrden = false;

                repeticiones = 4;
                cantFig = 4;
           }


    public void guardaconf1()
    {
        //ClaseFigura[] fig = new ClaseFigura[/*cantfig*/];

    }

    public string MuestraDirectorio()
        {
            return directorio;
        }

    public void EditaDirectorio(string a)
    {
        directorio = a;
    }

    public void EditaOrden(bool a)
    {
        confOrden = a;
    }

}
```

Y una ventana de configuración llamada VentConfiguracion.cs, pondré solo lo mas importante y no toda la clase:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

public partial class VentConfiguracion : Window
{
    private Configuracion config;
    private Sujeto s1, s2;
    private EdicionFiguras Edicion;
    private ClaseFigura[] Fig;

    StackPanel[] Miniaturas = new StackPanel[8];

    public VentConfiguracion(ref Configuracion c, ref Sujeto clases1, ref Sujeto clases2, ref EdicionFiguras ed, ref ClaseFigura[] f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        config=c;
        s1 = clases1; s2 = clases2;
        LabelDirectorio.Content = config.MuestraDirectorio();
        existenciaDirectorio();
        Miniaturas = new StackPanel[] { Mini1, Mini2, Mini3, Mini4, Mini5, Mini6, Mini7, Mini8 };
        Edicion = ed;
        Fig = f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            Miniaturas[i].Children.Add(Fig[i].dibujoMini);      // Imprime todos los mini poligonos
    }

 private void radioLista_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)           //Seleccionado En ORDEN LISTA
    {
        config.EditaOrden(false);
    }
```

Vale aclarar que en el MainWindows pasé por referencia una instancia de la clase Configuración en la clase VentConfiguración para así poder modificar las variables guardadas en configuración. Esta es una parte del main:

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

       public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Configuracion Config = new Configuracion();
        Sujeto sujeto1 = new Sujeto();
        Sujeto sujeto2 = new Sujeto();

        ClaseFigura[] Figura = new ClaseFigura[8];
        CargaDatosFiguras(ref Figura);

        EdicionFiguras Edic = new EdicionFiguras(Figura);
        VentConfiguracion c = new VentConfiguracion(ref Config, ref sujeto1, ref sujeto2, ref Edic, ref Figura);



        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        c.ShowDialog();

        ...

        }
```

El problema surge cuando quiero modificar alguna variable de Configuración dentro de la clase VentConfiguración por ejemplo con un RadioButton:

```
     private void radioLista_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)           //Seleccionado En ORDEN LISTA
    {
        config.EditaOrden(false);
    }
```

Cuando voy a ejecutar me aparece el siguiente error:

```
"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."
```

Entiendo el error, mi problema es que no se como solucionarlo.
Obviamente me faltan conceptos soy nuevo en programación orientada a objetos, muchas gracias.

Comment: como estas inicializando esa ventana? tener un constructor parametrizado para ventanas no es comun, ya quen nadie lo llama... o si? como lo estas haciendo?

Comment: En el Main? de la siguiente Forma:            

            Configuracion Config = new Configuracion();
         
            VentConfiguracion c = new VentConfiguracion(ref Config, ref sujeto1, ref sujeto2, ref Edic, ref Figura);

Comment: podes agregar tu main a la pregunta? para mi, no estas levantando la ventana que vos pensas que levantas

Comment: igual, por como la manejas, tu clase configuracion tranquilamente podria ser estatica

Comment: Acabo de agregar el MainWindows

Comment: que son todos esos ref? sabes que las variables pasan por ref por defecto no? mas alla de eso, el codigo esta bien. podes poner un breackpoint en el constructor y fijarte que efectivamente este pasando una sola vez por el?

Comment: Si, me di cuenta hace poco que los referencia por defecto, tengo que corregir eso. y si, por los contructores pasa siempre una vez al inicio del programa como podes ver en el main cuando declaro las nuevas clases. Pero sigo sin solucionar mi problema :S

Comment: no. yo tengo miedo, que pase 2 veces por tu constructor, por el constructor de VentConfiguracion. eso lo podes revisar? porque si tu variable de NPE, es que estas mirando otra ventana, no la que vos pensas. Podrias hacer un [mcve]?

Comment: Acabo de verificar con breakpoint y solo pasa una vez por el constructor de VentConfig en todo el programa

Comment: Estas seguro que config es nulo no? vamos a necesitar un ejemplo para reproducir el problema. el codigo que estas mandando a ojo, anda bien

Comment: Creo que el problema pasa más porque la clase "Configuracion config" que inicialicé en VentConfig es usada en funciones antes de que tome un valor en el constructor de VentConfig, no se si me entendés.

Comment: no. no entiendo.. en que funciones?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que config sea nulo, como puedo hacerlo nulo al inicializarlo? No entiendo a que te refieres con necesitar un ejemplo, disculpa mi ignorancia soy re nuevo en esto

Comment: en la función de radioLista_Checked

Comment: Pude solucionarlo de una manera poco agradable. Ya escribiré la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema pero no se si esta solución es correcta.
Cuando llamaba el constructor de la clase VentConfiguración

```
  public VentConfiguracion(Configuracion c,Sujeto clases1, Sujeto clases2, EdicionFiguras ed, ClaseFigura[] f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        config = c;
        s1 = clases1; s2 = clases2;
        LabelDirectorio.Content = config.MuestraDirectorio();
        existenciaDirectorio();
        Miniaturas = new StackPanel[] { Mini1, Mini2, Mini3, Mini4, Mini5, Mini6, Mini7, Mini8 };
        Edicion = ed;
        Fig = f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            Miniaturas[i].Children.Add(Fig[i].dibujoMini);      // Imprime todos los mini poligonos
    }
```

Vemos que primero se Inicializan los componentes (InitializeComponent()) de la clase, esto hace llamar a todas las funciones que tenga esta clase incluidas las funciones que están usando la clase Configuración, que en ese momento es nula porque se le da un valor recién en el momento siguiente cuando hacemos config=c; 
Entonces lo que hice fue poner la asignación de config antes de la inicialización de componentes de la clase.

```
  public VentConfiguracion(Configuracion c,Sujeto clases1, Sujeto clases2, EdicionFiguras ed, ClaseFigura[] f)
    {
        config = c;
        InitializeComponent();
        s1 = clases1; s2 = clases2;
        LabelDirectorio.Content = config.MuestraDirectorio();
        existenciaDirectorio();
        Miniaturas = new StackPanel[] { Mini1, Mini2, Mini3, Mini4, Mini5, Mini6, Mini7, Mini8 };
        Edicion = ed;
        Fig = f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            Miniaturas[i].Children.Add(Fig[i].dibujoMini);      // Imprime todos los mini poligonos
    }
```

La verdad no se si está bien, no parece muy elegante pero funciona porque cuando la iniciaización va a buscar a config éste ya tiene un valor.

Comment: Entonces config la estas usando en otro lado ademas de donde la mostraste. Pq initializecomponents levanta solo los componetes de wpf. Y ese codigo es autogenerado, asi que donde lo estas usando?